# How to reload a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I want to reload a `UIWebView` (including all labels and images) when a button is tapped. How can I do that?

Comment: Buddy, going back and marking some answers as accepted sure will go a long way toward helping people help you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [webView reload];
}
```

or

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.OurLovingMother.org/Mobile.aspx"];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]];
}
```

Comment: `[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]];` is better

Comment: As of iOS 8 (?) this is no longer the same. loading the same URL will not necessarily reload the content.

Answer (score 10):

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked
{
   [yourWebview reload];
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you load the content of your `UIWebView` using `loadHTMLString:` then you'll need to call `loadHTMLString:` again to reload it. In this case the `reload` method doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
[webView reload];
```

in your click handler.