# IOS/Objective-C: Force UIWebView to reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a screen that shows a web view. However, I allow people to cycle through different web views by updating an object. When I load the first page, the web view loads fine.  However, when I try to update the page from the new object in `viewwillappear`, while other elements such as a title that goes above the webview load fine, the web view does not refresh.

```
//in viewWillAppear
self.title = self.file.imageDescript;//The title loads fine
    NSString *urlBase = @"https://www.~com/images/";
     NSString * imagename = self.file.imagename;
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",urlBase,imagename]; 
    NSURL *realUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:realUrl];
    [webView loadRequest:request];



 I have tried various versions of setNeedsDisplay and also applied these to subviews of the web view without success as in this method:


- (void) forceRedrawInWebView:(UIWebView*)webView {
    NSArray *views = webView.scrollView.subviews;

    for(int i = 0; i<views.count; i++){
        UIView *view = views[i];

        //if([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebBrowserView"]){
        [view setNeedsDisplayInRect:webView.bounds]; // Webkit Repaint, usually fast
        [view setNeedsLayout]; // Webkit Relayout (slower than repaint)

        // Causes redraw & relayout of *entire* UIWebView, onscreen and off, usually intensive
        [view setNeedsDisplay];
        [view setNeedsLayout];
        // break; // glass in case of if statement (thanks Jake)
        //}
    }
}
```

I have read in one SO answer that since IOS8.2, refresh of `UIWebView` no longer works (as `WKWebView`) has replaced it.  I would switch to `WKWebView` except that it is not supported in storyboards, apparently, and I have a bunch of stuff going on in the storyboard.

Note: this has nothing to do with refreshing the same web url because content has changed on a server.  It has to do with loading an entirely different web url in the UIWebView

Can anyone suggest way to fix this?

Comment: I don´t know if I understand your question, you are trying to reload your UIWebView but with another url?

Comment: Just set the new url to the webview will reload it

Comment: @geneCode.  That is the issue.  It does not reload when you change url and call [webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: @Reiner.  I want to load a different url i.e. webpage.  I change the value of request to a different url but it does not load the webpage at that url.

Comment: See Manmal's comment here that as of 8/2, reloading url does not update web view:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878832/how-to-reload-a-uiwebview